# How can I make a discord bot that sends input from a form to a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot for staff applications, but I'm having trouble sending the input to discord. The way it currently works is someone fills out a form, that is then sent to my server, but I'm having trouble sending it to discord.

Comment: Sounds like something Webhooks are perfect for as opposed to a bot (also supported by the library).

Comment: You could either use webhooks or, if both of us have the same understanding of a "form" you could make a slash (or prefixed) command that calls modal, which essentially would allow you to make a Discord built-in form. Then, you can both send it to your server and back to discord.